# SQL Server: I need to create copies of records from 2 tables and ensure FK reflects these copies

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server 2016, I need to create nearly exact copies of records from 2 tables. The only difference will be their primary keys, one other column that I'm resetting to zero, and a foreign key in my 2nd table (which is the PK of my 1st table). I can create copies of both tables fine, however I don't know how to assign new FK values to the 2nd table, to correctly reflect the new primary keys from the 1st table.

Here are the current records in both tables:

Table 1: **Batches**

```
+-----------------------+-----------+----------------+------------+
| BatchID (pk identity) | StartDate | ProcessingStep | BatchCount |
+-----------------------+-----------+----------------+------------+
|                     1 | 5/10/2019 |              2 |       8203 |
|                     2 | 5/11/2019 |              2 |        345 |
|                     3 | 5/12/2019 |              2 |       5014 |
+-----------------------+-----------+----------------+------------+
```

Table 2: **ItemList**

```
+--------------------------+---------+--------+-----------+-------------+
| ItemListID (pk identity) | BatchID | ItemID | Processed | ProcessDate |
+--------------------------+---------+--------+-----------+-------------+
|                     1000 |       1 |    201 |         1 | 5/10/2019   |
|                     1001 |       1 |    689 |         1 | 5/10/2019   |
|                     1002 |       2 |    548 |         1 | 5/11/2019   |
|                     1003 |       2 |    693 |         1 | 5/11/2019   |
|                     1004 |       3 |    123 |         1 | 5/12/2019   |
|                     1005 |       3 |    999 |         1 | 5/12/2019   |
+--------------------------+---------+--------+-----------+-------------+
```

I now want to create copies of these records with the following exceptions:

- `Batches.ProcessingStep` for all records will now be set to zero
- `ItemList`'s `Processed` & `ProcessDate` are reset to zero & null respectively
- Update `ItemList.BatchID` to reflect the new PK of the copied `Batches` records (this is where I'm having trouble)

Currently, my script for updating my tables is as follows:

```
INSERT INTO Batches(StartDate, ProcessingStep, BatchCount)
    SELECT StartDate, 0, BatchCount 
    FROM Batches 
    WHERE BatchID IN (1,2,3)

INSERT INTO ItemList(BatchID, ItemID, Processed, ProcessDate)
     SELECT <<?? not sure ??>>, ItemID, 0, NULL 
     WHERE ItemListID BETWEEN 1000 AND 1005
```

And here would be my final results:

Table 1: **Batches**

```
+---------+-----------+----------------+------------+
| BatchID | StartDate | ProcessingStep | BatchCount |
+---------+-----------+----------------+------------+
|       1 | 5/10/2019 |              2 |       8203 |
|       2 | 5/11/2019 |              2 |        345 |
|       3 | 5/12/2019 |              2 |       5014 |
|       4 | 5/10/2019 |              0 |       8203 |
|       5 | 5/11/2019 |              0 |        345 |
|       6 | 5/12/2019 |              0 |       5014 |
+---------+-----------+----------------+------------+
```

Table 2: **ItemList**

```
+------------+---------+--------+-----------+-------------+
| ItemListID | BatchID | ItemID | Processed | ProcessDate |
+------------+---------+--------+-----------+-------------+
|       1000 |       1 |    201 |         1 | 5/10/2019   |
|       1001 |       1 |    689 |         1 | 5/10/2019   |
|       1002 |       2 |    548 |         1 | 5/11/2019   |
|       1003 |       2 |    693 |         1 | 5/11/2019   |
|       1004 |       3 |    123 |         1 | 5/12/2019   |
|       1005 |       3 |    999 |         1 | 5/12/2019   |
|       1006 |       4 |    201 |         0 | NULL        |
|       1007 |       4 |    689 |         0 | NULL        |
|       1008 |       5 |    548 |         0 | NULL        |
|       1009 |       5 |    693 |         0 | NULL        |
|       1010 |       6 |    123 |         0 | NULL        |
|       1011 |       6 |    999 |         0 | NULL        |
+------------+---------+--------+-----------+-------------+
```

How would I go about populating that `ItemList.BatchID` foreign key correctly?

Thanks.

Comment: Is BatchID an identity? You could create a temp table and then use the OUTPUT clause to capture the old and new BatchID. Then join to that in the insert to the details table.

Comment: BatchID (and ItemListID) is an identity, yes.  I've editted my question to reflect that, thanks